# using custom event listener java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up a custom event listener from my MainActivity to another singleton class and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I've got a map fragment set up in my mainactivity and when onLocationChanged() is called I want my DB class to listen for this new location to add it to my database. This is what I have so far. I'm only showing the code relevant to the interface and listener:

MainActivity.java

```
public List<OnNewLocationRaisedListener> locationListeners;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    locationListeners = new ArrayList<OnNewLocationRaisedListener>();
    ...
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    WeatherDBAccess._context = this;
    m_CurrentLocation = location;
    WeatherEvent event = new WeatherEvent();

    if (record) {
        LatLng currLatLng = new LatLng(m_CurrentLocation.getLatitude(), m_CurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        for(OnNewLocationRaisedListener listener: locationListeners){
            listener.OnNewLocationRaised(event,currLatLng);
        }

    }
}

public interface OnNewLocationRaisedListener {
    void OnNewLocationRaised(WeatherEvent event, LatLng latlon);
}
```

In My WeatherDBAccess.java class I try setting it up so that I can add its context to mNewLocationListeners list, but it won't allow me to do this, I get a 'non static field cannot be referenced from a static context' error and I don't know how to fix it:

WeatherDBAccess.java:

```
public class WeatherDBAccess extends SQLiteAssetHelper
            implements MainActivity.OnNewLocationRaisedListener {
    public static WeatherDBAccess Instance() {
        if(_context == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("You must supply the WeatherDBAccess._context prior to calling Instance()");

        if(_instance == null)
            _instance = new WeatherDBAccess(_context);

        return _instance;
    }

    public WeatherDBAccess(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d("WeatherDBAccess", "Instance Created " + db.getPath());

        MainActivity.locationListeners.add(this); //error

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void OnNewLocationRaised(WeatherEvent event, LatLng latlon ) {
        addTravelData(event); //this method puts the event & latlon into my database

    }
}
```

Can I just not do this from an activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainActivity.locationListeners` is an instance member and cannot be accessed statically like you are currently trying to do in `WeatherDbAccess`.

What you should do instead since `WeatherDBAccess` is a singleton is register and unregister it as a `locationListener` from within `MainActivity`. It should be in the same life cycle callback methods you are registering and unregistering the `LocationListener`.

Since you aren't showing that code lets assume it is in `onResume()` and `onPause()` but you can put the add and remove methods wherever they really belong.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationListeners.add(WeatherDBAccess.Instance());
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationListeners.remove(WeatherDBAccess.Instance());
}
```